# Does N7 level in multiplayer do anything?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

Does the N7 level in multiplayer do anything; like unlocking features or effecting placements for games, or is it just an indicator of how much multiplayer the person have played?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has no effect on any aspect other than how other players may treat you. I don't know if they use [truskill](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/trueskill/) in *ME3* (I don't think they do, but I was unable to find any indication one way or the other), but that would be how they would match you if they did. Otherwise it is likely just random. I have been in matches with all low levels (like me) and in matches with all really high levels (150+).

Comment: I wouldn't play Silver with a character bellow level 10 - unless his N7 rating is at least 100+ - preferably 200+

Answer (score 4):

It is a combination of the levels of your multiplayer characters & has no effect on your game.

Comment: Yes, but what i would like to know is if it have any effect on the game? like placement or unlocking features?
Will update question to make it more clear.

Comment: Then no. Your initial question was "Dose the N7 level in multiplayer do anything or is it just an indicator of how much multiplayer the person have played?" I have adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: There's also a +10 bonus each time you promote.

Answer (score -1):

I think it actually stands for something. When my level was below 300 the "rest skill points" item appeared as a gold item. Once I surpassed the lvl 300 it became silver. I think the higher the level the higher the odds to get better weapons and items such as black widows or other N7 guns

Comment: This is unrelated to N7 level, and in fact, represents a recent patch change. See [here](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/343/index/9544143#12086129), second to last note.